# How to perform transaction which includes both firebase real-time database and firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase Realtime Database and Firestore for my project. We can perform batch operations on firebase Realtime Database using `updateChildren()` and `commit()` on Firestore. But I have to perform a batch operation which includes some parts of Realtime Database and some part of Firestore. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to run a single transaction across both Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database.

You'll have to find a way to write the data in two separate transactions, and make sure your code that reads the data is robust enough to handle the case where one transaction has completed while the other hasn't.

Comment: If I could add some customer feedback here - I really hope this is possible one day. It would really put me at ease with something I'm trying to do in my project. My alternative here is to write some background code to check if there is any data that didn't get written properly for one particular task. It would be nice not to have to worry about that.